# Adding multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

I want to input prices into multiple boxes, with 1 box defaulting to a certain value. The following code only adds the values as strings. How can I do this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>


Package Price <input type="number" id="pkg">      </input><br>
Equipment Package <input type="number" id="pep" value="11.25"></input><br>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>   

<font size="12"> Total </font><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test()

{
var userInput = document.getElementById("pkg").value;
var userInput2 = document.getElementById("pep").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput + userInput2;
}

</script>
```

Comment: values from input are `string`. you need to convert it via `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test(){
    var userInput = (document.getElementById("pkg").value)*1;
    var userInput2 = (document.getElementById("pep").value)*1;    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput + userInput2;
}
```

this will work !!

http://jsfiddle.net/4ou4f6kh/

Comment: to expand on this, i added some radio buttons...how can i add the selected radio button to the total?

Comment: I just made an update in the fiddle have a look in it http://jsfiddle.net/4ou4f6kh/1/